# If you notice something you will see vs If you see something you will notice

Tags: verbs, sentence-choice

> When you are reading and you want to pay attention to a special word (for example colour_number), do you **see** the special word and **notice** how it is formed?

or

> …you **notice** the special word and **see** how it is formed.

I am writing a how to and the reader should pay attention to a word to then pay attention to how to do something. I do not know if somebody see and then notice, if somebody firstly notice and then see, or if this is a dumb question.

If prefer to see and then to notice because firstly you have to see the word and then realize about that, but the other one sounds good to me.

Comment: maybe if you see something you will *realize* and if you notice something you will see?

Comment: Are you looking for something like "Please see the second line of page 42 and notice how the verb is conjugated using the past tense." ?

Comment: @Kevin  no, I am looking please see how the word is formed (actually it is more than one word joined by underscores) and then pay attention because it has a meaning. You have to notice (or realize?) that meaning.

Comment: *notice* requires a bit more attention and you use your cognition to *identify* the nuance of something. On the other hand, *seeing* is just *seeing*. Now, place them wherever you want and the *order* of your perception changes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer to your question is a but tricky since you are using **two different meanings** of two different words **see** and **notice**

> I **see** the bird
>   I ***observe*** the bird
>
> I **see** what you are saying
>   I ***understand*** what you are saying
>
> I **noticed** the bird in the tree
>   I ***observed*** the bird in the tree
>
> I **noticed** he was bending the rules
>   I ***realized*** he was bending the rules *(observed and understood)*

**First things first**: 
In order to **visually notice** something, one must first **physically see** it.

It is possible to

> **notice** the room getting warmer and then **see** the fire

but this **notice** is not **visual**

**Notice** can mean to **casually see**

> I **noticed** they came into the room but didn't **see** what they were doing

In your sentence

> do you **see** the special word and **notice** how it is formed?
>
> do you **see** the special word and ***realize*** how it is formed?
>   do you **see** the special word and ***understand*** how it is formed?

because you're using the word **notice** the reader could honestly answer that they **saw** and **observed** the word without **understanding** it

In your alternative sentence

> …you **notice** the special word and **see** how it is formed.
>   ...you ***look at*** the special word and ***understand*** how it is formed

You probably want the reader to *(using the imperatives)*

> **See!** the special word
>   **Look at!** the special word

**notice** is not an imperative, and then

> **understand** how it is formed
>   **figure out** how it is formed